# How can I import skimage in vs code python? It shows me the error like mentioned in the image and the text

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, scikit-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnMfN.jpg)

pip install skimage：

```
Collecting skimage
  Using cached skimage-0.0.tar.gz (757 bytes)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-auzblq4_\\skimage\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-auzblq4_\\skimage\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-9s1nfssp'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-auzblq4_\skimage\
    Complete output (3 lines):

    *** Please install the `scikit-image` package (instead of `skimage`) ***

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Try `pip install scikit-image`

Comment: @Coding Yogi  -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. If there is an answer that solves this problem, please [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as an answer to help others find this solution.

Comment: still it's not working for me, having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to "Please install the `scikit-image` package (instead of `skimage`)" in the information you provided, please install "[scikit-image](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-image/)":

[image]